# Should I put a comma after "is" if it's followed by a prepositional phrase?

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases, independent-clauses

> My thought is, if we are going to bring people to the table, that there will also be an opportunity for them.

I can't rearrange the sentence because I'm doing verbatim transcription.

Comment: Looks sensible to me. Are you not permitted to add brackets or italics for clarification of extempore speech ?

Comment: You are not putting a comma after _is_ per se; you are bracketing the if-clause with commas. If the speaker had said "My thought is that if… there would be no need for a comma before _if_, at least not since 1950 or so.

Comment: I know - I wish they had said it like that!!

Thank you!

Comment: I am having up to 20 comma rules during my study now.  The first part of the sentence looks like "introductory" and "additional info". Also the comma after "is" represents a well used pause, followed by the main-sentence, beginning with "if", therefore also seperated by a comma.

Comment: But my feel and according to KarlG, "My thought is that if we.... , that there will..... sounds ok.

Comment: Since the only point of your Question was whether or not the example should be rearranged, how can you say you can't do that?

IMHO most Questions about comma usage, including yours, belong not here but to English Language Learners.

That said, I would suggest "My thought is, if we are going to bring people to the table, there will be an opportunity for them…”

“that” adds what, please?

“also” adds what, please?

Even though “for them” appears to add something, grammatically, what does it add to the meaning, please?